# How to stop looping same data in foreach

Tags: laravel, loops, foreach, laravel-8

So, I make categories for `jawaban` and if `jawaban == 1` then `jawaban` input type should be a button radio and if `jawaban == 2` the input type should be multiple choice but when i am looping the condition `jawaban` would be looping for all `pertanyaans`, I just want to loop only for that `kegiatan`

[image: The Result]

[image: What I want]

in blade.php

```html
@foreach ($pertanyaans as $pertanyaan)
    @if ($pertanyaan->kategori1 == '1')
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="file" name="jawaban" id="jawaban" accept=".png, .jpeg, .jpg" data-allowed-file-extensions='["png", "jpeg", "jpg"]' id="input-file-now" class="dropify" data-max-file-size="3000K" />
            <p class="help-block" style="font-size: 12px;">Max Filesize 3 MB (png, jpeg, jpg)</p>
        </div>
    @endif
    @break($pertanyaan->kategori1 == 1)
    @if ($pertanyaan->kategori1 == '2')
        <div class="form-group">
            <textarea class="form-control" id="jawaban" rows="3"></textarea>
        </div>
    @endif
    
    @break($pertanyaan->kategori1 == 2)

    @if ($pertanyaan->kategori1 == '3')
        <div class="form-group" id="jawaban">
            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="pilihan" id="pilihan1" value="option1">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">Sangat Tidak Sesuai</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="pilihan" id="pilihan2" value="option2">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">Tidak Sesuai</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="pilihan" id="pilihan3" value="option1">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">Lumayan Sesuai</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="pilihan" id="pilihan4" value="option2">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">Sesuai</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="pilihan" id="pilihan5" value="option2">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">Sangat Sesuai</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endif
```

in my controller :

```php
$list_pelaporan = PelaporanEfektivitas::all();
$kategori = kategori_pertanyaan::all();
$kegiatan = kegiatan::all();
$pertanyaans = PertanyaanEfektivitas::all();

if ($request->ajax()) {
    return datatables()->of($list_pelaporan)
        ->addColumn('action', function ($data) {
            $button = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="tooltip"  data-id="'.$data->id.'" data-original-title="Edit" class="edit btn btn-primary edit-post"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Pelaporan</a>';
            $button .= '&nbsp;&nbsp;';
            $button .= '<button type="button" name="detail" data-toggle="tooltip" name="detail" data-id="'.$data->id.'" class="detail btn btn-info detail-modal"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> Detail</button>';
            $button .= '&nbsp;&nbsp;';
            $button .= '<button type="button" name="delete" id="'.$data->id.'" class="delete btn btn-danger"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i> Delete</button>';
            
            return $button;
        })
        ->rawColumns(['action'])
        ->addIndexColumn()
        ->make(true);
};

return view('pelaporan.efektivitas', compact('kategori','kegiatan','list_pelaporan', 'pertanyaans'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use `Switch Statements` for multiple conditions

```php
@switch($pertanyaan->kategori1)
    @case(1)
    // First case...
    @break

    @case(2)
    // Second case...
    @break

    @case(3)
    // Third case...
    @break

    @default
    // Default case...
@endswitch
```